# Table column width distribution

Tags: tabularx

I got the following table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pbox}

\title{Skills Matrix}
\author{Raphael Fritz}
\date{February 2019}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{Programming Languages}}   \\ \hline
Skill & Degree of \newline experience \footnote{test} & Commentary \\ \hline
Java & 3 & this is a very long text and it needs much space in here \\ \hline \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{test titel 2}} \\ \hline
           Skill & Degree of \newline experience & Commentary \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It looks like this

[image]

The second column does not need that much space. The last does need more space. Why are the second and third distributed equally? How can I change that?

And how do I get my table to full width of my paper?

Comment: You are asking for equally wide columns by making both `X` type (that means: the remaining space after regular columns is equally distributed among them). To make your table full paper width, you could reduce the margins.

Comment: @TeXnician Thank you. The problem is, that When not using X at the second column I can't do this line break.

Comment: Use e.g. `p{4cm}`.

Answer (score 1):

see, if this can help you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}  % <--

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht] % <--
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|>{\hsize=0.6\hsize}L|   % <--
                                >{\hsize=1.4\hsize}L|}  % <--
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{Programming Languages}}   \\ \hline
Skill & Degree of experience \footnote{test} & Commentary \\ \hline
Java & 3 & this is a very long text and it needs much space in here \\ \hline \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{test titel 2}} \\ \hline
           Skill & Degree of \newline experience & Commentary \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: when using `\hsize=...`, you forgot the sum of the coefficients should be the number of columns; so to obtain the same ratio, they should be 0.6 and 1.4.

Comment: @Bernard, your suggestion works, however, in `tabularx` documentation this not mentioned. from description: *"Make sure that the sum of the widths of all the X columns is unchanged. (In
the above example, the new widths still add up to twice the default width,
the same as two standard X columns.)"* i don't understand that one need to obey the rule noted in your comment. but it might be that i'm wrong.

Comment: I think that what's in the parenthesis explicits the rule: if you have 2 (ordinary) X columns hence 2 \hsizes, and  If you use `\hsize=...`, you have to ensure the total of coefficients will still make 2 \ihsizes in all. At least that's my interpretation.

Comment: @Zarko - If the relative widths of the two `X` columns form the ratio `0.3:0.7`, then their `\hsize`s *must* be 0.6 and 1.4, respectively. The sum of the `\hsize` values must equal the number of columns of type X.

Comment: thank you boths. i correct answer accordingly.